# how to represent element in the schema?

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, xsd

I'm working on spring based application. I have created a webservice to access from other application. Below is the DTO class.

MyDTO.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name=MyConstants.PROCESS_DATES)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
public class MyDTO{
@XmlElement(required = true,nillable=false)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(com.dis.time.JaxbLocalDateAdapter.class)
List<LocalDate> processDatesList;

//getters,setters here
}
```

MyConstants.java

```
public interface MyConstants{
String PROCESS_DATES = "GetProcessDatesResponse";
}
```

Below is the XSD schema:

```
<xsd:element name="GetProcessDatesResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="processDatesList" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
</xsd:all></xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

For the MyDTO.java class, above is the XSD schema. My questions is how to represent `List<LocalDate>` for the variable processDatesList in the above schema, i have mentioned as `type="xsd:String"`. Is that correct way to represent the schema for the above mentioned DTO class.Please advice.

PS:How to represent `List<LocalDate>` in the XSD schema.

Comment: You can use this maxOccurs="unbounded" where you need a collection of items

Comment: @Mechkov - ok. Do i need to mention minOccurs="0" and what should be the type? I have mentioned type="xsd:string" , is it the correct way to represent List<LocalDate>?

Comment: You can represent is as a String. Yes, you mentione minOccurs as well.